# How to set up BouncyCastle

Tags: java, import, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm having some trouble setting up bouncycastle.

I've downloaded the jar, put it in Java\jre1.8.0_271\lib\ext, added it to java.security in the providers list and added it to the classpath.

When trying `import org.bouncycastle...` I get the message 'bouncycastle cannot be resolved'

I have also tried `Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCasytleProvider());` but get the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also has to be in your class path.

If you're compiling building from command line use the `-cp` parameter and the `lib/ext` folder of the `JRE`.

If you're building in an IDE there is usually somewhere in the menus that lets you add folders to the class path. In IntelliJ it is in `File-->Project Structure-->Modules` and press the `+` sign.

Comment: It is already in my class path. I've gone into project structure and added it in the modules tab but am still getting the same error

Comment: Seems like an error of the IDE. In IntelliJ you can close the project, delete the `.idea` and `*.iml` file and reopen the project (and configure it)